# Exporting flash content to PDF?

Tags: php

I am using fpdf.php to export the PDF document from PHP. I'm still facing the problem that I couldn't export flash content in to the PDF

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by flash content? You should separate data generating code from data displaying code, so you can write two components for displaying data: one for flash and one for pdf.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to take a `.swf` file and convert it into a `PDF` then you will need to find a different solution since the *fpdpf.php* library, since it doesn't support converting `.swf` files into PDFs.